# How to ng-model on Firebase 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

i only need to set the ng-model value to this part:

```
db.ref('users').push({
      email: email,
      password: password
    });
```

With the code above, i get this error:

```
angular.js:14328 ReferenceError: email is not defined
```

If i set like this, the code work as well:

```
db.ref('users').push({
      email: 'test',
      password: 'password test'
    });
```

Heres the full JS:

```js
angular.module('myApp',["firebase" ])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$firebase){

  var config = {
    apiKey: "8888",
    authDomain: "8888",
    databaseURL: "8888",
    storageBucket: "8888",
    messagingSenderId: "8888"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var db = firebase.database();

  $scope.user={email:'',password:''}

  $scope.add = function(){
    db.ref('users').push({
      email: email,
      password: password
    });
  }



})
```

```html
<form>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="cadastro-email" class="estilo-input" type="text" name="nomeDoGrupo" placeholder="E-mail" ng-model="user.email" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="cadastro-senha" class="estilo-input" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" ng-model="user.password" />
                          </div>

                        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-xl" ng-click="add()">Entrar</a>
                      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line above you store the 'email' and 'password' in the '$scope.user' object, so you need to do this:

```
db.ref('users').push({
  email: $scope.user.email,
  password: $scope.user.password
});
```